# regex challenge

Tags: regex, email, html-email, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

I've got a little challenge that's bodering me for past 2 days.
I've have to chech if "From:" and "X-Sender:" have the same value using RegEx

Problem:

```
From: some text
<someone@mail.com>
X-Sender: notthatmail.com
```

How colud RegEx perform check if those two mails are matching?
This is actually a mail where I have to look form mail consistency of Mime headers.

Comment: can you share some example? which language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
From: .+?<(.+?)>.+?X-Sender: \1\b
```

If it matches, the two emails are the same.

Note that this requires the single line option to be on. If your regex flavour does not have a single line option, you can replace all the `.` with `[\s\S]` to achieve the same effect.

How this works:

It first finds the the email address in the <> brackets, captures it into group 1. And the it continues to look for the word `X-Sender:`. And then it asserts that there must be whatever is in group 1 (`\1`) after the word `X-Sender:`.

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/5WLIzR/1)

Comment: Thank you for that, you saved me a lot of time, btw can I make a negative of that.

Comment: @AntonioZunic Try `From: .+?<(.+?)>.+?X-Sender: (?!\1\b)`

Comment: If this is for something like a Firewall rule, be careful of these sorts of combinations, which will match a simple Regex.

From: some text 
<notthatmail.com>,<evil@evil.com> 
X-Sender: notthatmail.com